# view not gathering data from service through controller

Tags: json, angularjs, model-view

Having trouble loading an external json file and having it's contents display on my view. I've included my view, controller and services code. What do I need to change?

**view.html**

```
<div ng-controller='BaseCtrl'>
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <tbody>
           <tr class="tr-sep" ng-repeat="example in examples" ng-click="showUser(example)">
              <td>{{example.name}}</td>
              <td>{{example.type}}</td>
              <td>{{example.size}}</td>
           </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**controller.js**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('projyApp')
  .controller('BaseCtrl', function ($scope, data) {
    $scope.examples = data.getAllExamples();

    $scope.showUser = function(example) {
        window.location = '#/user/' +example.size;
    };

  });
```

**service.js**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('projyApp')
  .service('data', function data() {
        var examples;

        var getAllExamples = function () {

            $http.get("../../TestData/Examples.json").success($scope.examples = data.examples);
        };

  });
```

Comment: in your service you need to return data.examples and not assign it to $scope. $scope is undefined in the data service.

Comment: console: "TypeError: Object #<data> has no method 'getAllObservers'
    at new <anonymous>"

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your posted code getAllObservers function. Can you make a JsFiddle?

Comment: my bad, getAllExamples is what I meant to type.

Comment: data service should return the function. i.e: `return { getAllExamples:getAllExamples}`

Comment: Is that your actual service code? It doesn't seem correct at all.

Comment: @MichaelBenford yeah it is, what appears incorrect?

Comment: @captainrad I've just posted an answer explaning the issues I see in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your service code isn't correct. I see the following problems:

- You're creating a local variable `getAllExamples` that's not accessible from outside the service;
- You're using the `$http` service, but that dependency isn't expressed in the service constructor;
- You're trying to update the scope from the service, but it's inaccessible from there. Plus, the `$scope` variable is not even defined inside the service code.

Here's how your service could look like:

```
.service('data', function($http) {
    this.getAllExamples = function(callback) {
        $http.get("../../TestData/Examples.json")
            .success(function(data) {
                if (callback) callback(data.examples);
            });
        };
});
```

And your controller code would be like this:

```
.controller('BaseCtrl', function ($scope, data) {
    data.getAllExamples(function(examples) {
        $scope.examples = examples;
    });

    $scope.showUser = function(example) {
        window.location = '#/user/' +example.size;
    };
});
```

You could ditch the callback in the `getAllExamples` function and work directly with the `$http.get`returned promise, but that's a bit more complicated.

**Update** Added a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xNfguhWFl5mPvHPRG8H6?p=preview) script to illustrate the code above.

Comment: I updated the post to include a Plunker script. It's working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Main module definition should look like:

```
angular.module("projyApp",[/*dependencies go here*/]);
```

Service should look like

```
//this use of module function retrieves the module
//Note from comments in angular doc: This documentation should warn that "angular.module('myModule', [])" always creates a new module, but "angular.module('myModule')" always retrieves an existing reference.)
angular.module('projyApp')
  .service('dataService', [/*dependencies,*/function() {
        var service = {
            examples:[],
            getAllExamples = function () {

                $http.get("../../TestData/Examples.json").success(function(returnedData){examples = returnedData});
            }
       }
       return service;
  });
```

Controller should look like:

```
angular.module('projyApp')
  .controller('BaseCtrl', function ($scope, dataService) {
    $scope.examples = [];

    $scope.showUser = function(example) {
        window.location = '#/user/' +example.size;
    };
    $scope.$watch(function(){return dataService.examples}, function(newVal,oldVal) {$scope.examples = newVal});

  });
```

Also you can add

```
debugger;
```

on an line to trigger Chrome to break (like a breakpoint but without having to dig through the scripts at run-time) so long as the Debugging Panel is open (F12)

Comment: this line: $http.get("../../TestData/Examples.json").success(function(returnedData){examples = returnedData}); is giving me an unexpected "="

Answer (score 0):

You should use a callback instead of assigning in to a `scope` in you data service. By doing that, you can use this function in multiple controllers an assign values to appropriate `scopes`.

**Data Service**

```
  var getAllExamples = function (callback) {

            $http.get("../../TestData/Examples.json").success(function(data) {
                if (typeof callback === "function") callback(data);
            });
   };
```

**Controller**

```
data.getAllExemples(function(data) {
    $scope.examples = data;
});
```

**EDIT**

Another what is to create a promise object.

**Data Service**

```
  var getAllExamples = function () {

            return $http.get("../../TestData/Examples.json");
   };
```

**Controller**

```
var promise = data.getAllExemples();

promise.then(function(data) {
   $scope.examples = data;
});
```

**EDIT 2**

In your service, you need to return your functions

```
angular.module('projyApp')
  .service('data', function data() {
        var examples;

     return {
            getAllExamples: function () {

                 $http.get("../../TestData/Examples.json").success(...);

            }
};

  });
```

Comment: You can also bind the promise directly to the view and Angular will automatically render the data as soon as the promise gets resolved.

Comment: console is printing "Object #<data> has no method 'getAllObservers'" for this aswell.